# How to split a dictionary of df in half using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large dictionary of dataframes. It contains around 250 dataframes, each of which has around 50 columns per df. My goal is to concat the dataframes to create one large df; however, as you can imagine, this process isn't great because it will create a df that is way too large view outside of using python.
My goal is to explode the large dictionary of df in half and turn it into two large, but manageable files.

I will try to replicate what it looks like:

```
d = {df1, df2,........,df500}
df = pd.concat(d) 
# However, Is there a way to split 50%?
df1 = pd.concat(d) # only gets first 250 of the df
df2 =pd.concat(d) # only gets last 250 df
```

Comment: That's not a dict it's a set:`d = {df1, df2,........,df500}`. Dicts have key-value pairs, sets only have elements. And df doesn't mean a dict, it means a dataframe.

Comment: @smci Of course you're right, but it's possible the OP was just formulating the data structure incorrectly for the post and in reality it *is* a dict. I'm guessing so by the fact that my answer, which assumed it was a dict as the OP said, was accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
v = list(d.values())
part1 = v[:len(v)//2]
part2 = v[len(part1):]

df1 = pd.concat(part1)
df2 = pd.concat(part2)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all it's not a dictionary , it's a set which can be converted to list.
An List can be divided into 2 as you need.

```
d=list(d)
ln=len(d)
d1=d[0:ln//2]
d2=d[ln//2:]
df1 = pd.concat(d1)
df2 = pd.concat(d2)
```

Comment: I think you might need to do `//2` instead of `/2` because the latter will return a float...?

Comment: @richardec  You are right.